# Chamar método no bean caso condição seja true

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, primefaces

Criei este confirm:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function salvarAntes(){
            var r=confirm("Deseja confirmar?");
                if(r){
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            </script>
```

E chamo no meu commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton value="Confirma" process="@form" onclick="if(salvarAntes() #{bean.salvar});"/>
```

A idéia é chamar o método no bean somente se oo meu javascript ser true. O problema é que no onclick fala que não encontra o método. Alguém sabe como posso resolver?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o componente do PrimeFaces <`p:remoteCommand>` para fazer isso.

Exemplo:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" actionListener="#{bean.salvar}"/>
```

E no seu botao voce faria:

```
<p:commandButton value="Confirma" process="@form" onclick="salvarAntes()"/>
```

E voce pode chamar seu remoteCommand com javascript assim:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function salvarAntes(){
        var r = confirm("Deseja confirmar?");
            if(r){
                rc(); //make a remote call
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
      }
</script>
```